# Typescript typing issue, Observable.next method not properly typed

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

Hi guys I'm really stuck on the following:

### Code:

**data-bank.propertiesClass.ts**

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/";

interface HomepageTextItems {
    header: string;
    items: string[];
}

export interface HomepageText {
    basics: HomepageTextItems;
    advanced: HomepageTextItems;
    practice: HomepageTextItems;
    blog: HomepageTextItems;
}


interface DataObject<T> {
    value?: T;
    observable: Subject<T>;
}

export class DataBankItems {
    public homepageText: DataObject<HomepageText> = this.createDataObject();
    // public website: DataObject<string> = this.createDataObject();
    public website2: DataObject<number> = this.createDataObject();

    private createDataObject<T>(): DataObject<T> {
        return {
            value: undefined,
            observable: new Subject<T>(),
        };
    }
}
```

**data-bank-services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { DataBankItems } from "./data-bank.propertiesClass";

// Important unsubscribe from the Subjects is the resonsibility of the subscribers in ngOnDestroy!
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
})
export class DataBankService {
    private dataBank = new DataBankItems();

    public updateValue<T extends keyof DataBankItems>(
        property: T,
        newValue: DataBankItems[T]["value"]
    ): void {
        this.dataBank[property].value = newValue;

        this.dataBank[property].observable.next(newValue);
    }

    public getObservable<T extends keyof DataBankItems>(property: T): DataBankItems[T]["observable"] {
        return this.dataBank[property].observable;
    }

    public getValue<T extends keyof DataBankItems>(property: T): DataBankItems[T]["value"] {
        return this.dataBank[property].value;
    }
}
```

I get the following error (strictnullchecks are on) in the line

`this.dataBank[property].observable.next(newValue);`

> Argument of type 'DataBankItems[T]["value"]' is  not assignable to
> parameter of type '(HomepageText & number) | undefined'.   Type
> 'number | HomepageText | undefined' is  not assignable to type
> '(HomepageText & number) | undefined'.

I have tried non null operator and type guards with !== undefined but no luck so far.

The problem seems that the next function expects type:

`'(HomepageText & number) | undefined'`

But gets:

`'HomepageText | number | undefined'` this is the type === `DataBankItems[T]["value"]`

I'm Really puzzled why it is expecting `'(HomepageText & number) | undefined'`. This seems like a bogus type to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't know in detail how the typescript compiler is working in this case.

But if you check the type of `this.dataBank[property].observable` that will be `Subject<HomepageTest> | Subject<number>`. Apparently this is different from `Subject<HomepageTest | number>` and typescript is expecting for the `next()` function a type intersection (`HomepageTest & number`) instead of a type union (`HomepageTest | number`).

As a quick solution you can store the type of`newValue` and cast the observable to accept that type:

```
public updateValue<T extends keyof DataBankItems>(
        property: T,
        newValue: DataBankItems[T]["value"]
    ): void {
        type P = DataBankItems[T]["value"];
        this.dataBank[property].value = newValue;
        (this.dataBank[property].observable as Subject<P>).next(newValue);
    }
```

Comment: I now have this         

(this.dataBank[property].observable as Subject<DataBankItems[T]["value"]>).next(
            newValue
        );

And it seems to work ;)

Comment: The type P is not needed though